# Node server not being able to connect to NATS server

Tags: node.js, certificate, nats.io

I'm trying to connect to a NATS server via nodejs and I'm running into issues with the cert.

The NATS server is behind a company VPN. Not sure if that is the issue. I can connect to the server itself when authenticated to the VPN but my code can't.

Here is the minimal code I'm trying when connecting:

```js
const creds = `-----BEGIN NATS USER JWT-----
    eyJ0eXAiOiJqdSDJB....
  ------END NATS USER JWT------

  -----BEGIN USER NKEY SEED-----
    SUAIBDPBAUTW....
  ------END USER NKEY SEED------
`;

async connectToNats(){
 let connection;
 try{
    connection = await connect({
      servers:[`nats://stage-nats1.company.net:4222`],
      debug: true,
      authenticator: credsAuthenticator(new TextEncoder().encode(creds)),
    });
    connection.subscribe('topicImInterestedIn')
}catch(e)
  console.log(e)
}
```

Error:

```bash
Error [ERR_TLS_CERT_ALTNAME_INVALID] hostname/IP does not match certificate's altnames: Host: localhost. is not the cert's altnames: DNS:*.companyName.net, DNS:companyName.net

    reason: "Host: localhost. is not in the cert's altnames: DNS:*.companyName.net, DNS:companyName.net
```

I'm confused why this is trying to connect to localhost when I specify that the server already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was that I needed both the creds, aka `NATS user jwt` and `nKey` and setup `tlsOptions` with a `cert.pem` and `cert.key` files added to the connection.

```js
//Should really be read from file
const creds = `-----BEGIN NATS USER JWT-----
    eyJ0eXAiOiJqdSDJB....
  ------END NATS USER JWT------

  -----BEGIN USER NKEY SEED-----
    SUAIBDPBAUTW....
  ------END USER NKEY SEED------
`;

const tlsOptions = {
  key: fs.readFileSync("key.pem"),
  cert: fs.readFileSync("cert.pem")
};
const nc = await connect({
  servers: ["nats://localhost:4222"],
  tls: tlsOptions,
  authenticator: credsAuthenticator(new TextEncoder().encode(creds)),
});
```